# VSCode Keybinding for Notebook output scroll

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim, vscode-keybinding, vs-code-settings

I am trying to create keybindings to scroll VSCode Notebook output with HJKL keys once the notebook output has been focused. This is what I had tried unsuccessfully:

```json
[
    // Scroll Notebook cell output
    {
        "key": "k",
        "command": "workbench.action.interactivePlayground.arrowUp",
        "when": "notebookOutputFocused"
    },
    {
        "key": "j",
        "command": "workbench.action.interactivePlayground.arrowDown",
        "when": "notebookOutputFocused"
    }
]
```

Arrow keys, Page Up/Down, Home/End seems to work.

Also is there a command in VSCode that can focus on the notebook output and scroll it into view? `Notebook: Focus In Active Cell Output` focuses the output but doesn't center it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use arrow keys (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/180569). I'm not aware of there being a binding to change this. If you want that, you should [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: Thanks @starball5, I have raised a feature request for [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204961)